# RadiateOut with css animation

Tags: css

I had a question to all the css wizards out there. I came across this CSS animation effect I have not seen before and wondered if anyone knew how it was done? https://www.landr.com/en

Just curious.

Best regards,
Philippe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a pseudo element to draw the circle that will radiate out, then use `transform: scale()` and `opacity` to cause it to grow and fade out.

using `animation`

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}

div:hover::after {
  animation: radiate .5s;
}

div, div::after {
  background: #09c;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@keyframes radiate {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or using `transition`

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}

div:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s;
}

div, div::after {
  background: #09c;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Wow! You just made it look too easy! Thank you very much for clarifying that for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: If I would want to only have the effect on hover but not on 'Mouse out'. What would need to be added to the code?

Comment: @Exposian ah, either transition the change on the `:hover` pseudo class or you can use an animation. updated my answer with both.

Comment: Thanking you very much!